# How to check if $_POST[image] is set

Tags: php, mysql, file, post, isset

Re asking [how to check if $_POST[FILE] isset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628854/how-to-check-if-postfile-isset?noredirect=1#comment82215158_47628854)
I have a file input and if I submit my form without an image I want something to happen if I uploaded a file in the input I want something different to happen.

```
if (!isset($_POST[image])) { }
```

seems to trigger regardless of whether or not I have uploaded a file in the input or not.

```
<label>
    <p>Profile Picture:</p>
    <input type="file" name="image" value="" />
</label>
```

My last question was marked as a duplicate of this answer [Check whether file is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630252/check-whether-file-is-uploaded) however

```
if (!file_exists($_FILE['image'])) { }
```

didn't work either it is still showing truthy even when an image is uploaded. So not the answer I need.

Comment: do a `print_r` for both or `var_dump` and see what happens. Do so for both with and without file

Comment: its `$_FILES` and not `$_FILE`

Comment: This is now sending an error of Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given And it's also breaking my header(); and it is STILL truthy even when a file is uploaded.

Comment: And when I don't put in a file and use if (empty($_FILES['image'])) { it is also truthy. Must I be missing something bigger here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if there is a file uploaded is you need to check the size of the file.

Then to check if its an image or not is you need to use the getimagesize() function. See my script below:

HTML:

```
<form action="index.php?act=s" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" value=""/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php  
if(isset($_GET['act'])){
    // Check if there is a file uploaded
    if($_FILES["image"]["size"]>0){
        echo "There is a file uploaded<br>";
        // Check if its an image
            $check_if_image = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check_if_image !== false) {
                echo "Image = " . $check_if_image["mime"] . ".";            
            } else {
                echo "Not an image";            
            }
    }
    else{
        echo "There is NO file uploaded<br>";
    }   
}   
?>
```

Comment: So I changed this to if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] = 0) { } it is still truthy when I have a file uploaded.

Comment: HAHAHA It's late I missed an = in that so of course it was truthy. I think this answer solved my problem let me test and verify then I will accept.